# Webpack - Babel - Parsing JSX: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: webpack, babeljs, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a React application using webpack. I am using babel to transpile .jsx files. But it seems, it is not using babel loader to load .jsx file. I am receiving following error:

```
ERROR in ./app.jsx
Module parse failed: C:\codebase\react-demo/app\app.jsx Unexpected token (7:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:15)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseReturnStatement (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:839:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:699:34)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseFunctionBody (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2105:24)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMethod (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2075:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClassMethod (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1137:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClass (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1118:14)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:697:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at C:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:439:3)
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var __dirname = path.resolve();

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/app",
    entry: "./app.jsx",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/",
        filename: "bundle.min.js"
    },
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
    }],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        })
    ],
};
```

My app.jsx (located in ./app/app/jsx) is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div > Test < /div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I have following `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

I have following node dependencies installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
}
```

Any idea what could I be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the loader configuration.

Property `loaders` should be in object `module`.

```
module.exports = {
    …
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }],
    },
    …
};
```

See https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html

Comment: Thank you Jokka. That was the issue. Moving the `loaders` in `module` solved the problem.